# Docusign Connection issue

Tags: docusignapi

We are using the Docusign Rest API to integrate with our application to send documents for signing.

The below mentioned is the connection string that is formed during runtime

Connection String =
weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection:https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information

When we try to get response from the connection, we get the following error
java.net.ConnectException: Tried all: 1 addresses, but could not connect over
HTTPS to server: demo.docusign.net port: 443;

Any pointers in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Rashmi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is coming from the weblogic stack.  Therefore, things to try:

1. Ensure that your server has Internet connectivity to https://demo.docusign.net by pinging from the console.
2. Check for https connectivity by using curl or similar.
3. Check that you're using the right method from your stack for https connections.

Since https://demo.docusign.net is definitely up and working (try it from a browser) the problem is local. Consult your stack vendor for additional help.